# How can I POST data to a React Native app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

I know how to POST data *from* a React Native app to the server with axios, but I don't know how I can POST data from the server to React Native. Is there a way to listen for requests from the server, or a way to handle requests to "routes" in the app (if they even exist)?

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by "POST data from the server to React Native"?
React Native is client, and you can't possibly fire a HTTP request to client. If you want to trigger something in React Native from the server, you can just use some real time bi-directional connection. Like HTTP/2 or socket.io, or just simple as long polling

Answer (score 1):

Either you are looking for

- `Sockets` (full duplex) a persistent communication channel between client and server
- or there might be a miss understanding on your end on how client server architecture is supposed to work, where a client usually only sends requests (and the server replies with a response)
- and then there is long polling (half duplex)

You might want to read up on this topics.